# Receiving data in TCP

Tags: c#, c++, networking, tcp

If i send 1000 bytes in TCP, does it guarantee that the receiver will get the entire 1000 bytes "togther"? or perhaps he will first only get 500 bytes, and later he'll receive the other bytes?

**EDIT**: the question comes from the application's point of view. If the 1000 bytes are reassembles into a single buffer before they reach the application .. then i don't care if it was fragmented in the way..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [Transmission Control Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol):

> TCP provides reliable, ordered delivery of a stream of bytes from a program on one computer to another program on another computer.

A "stream" means that there is no message boundary from the receiver's point of view. You could get one 1000 byte message or one thousand 1 byte messages depending on what's underneath and how often you call read/select.

**Edit**: Let me clarify from the application's point of view. No, TCP will not guarantee that the single read would give you all of the 1000 bytes (or 1MB or 1GB) packet the sender may have sent. Thus, a protocol above the TCP usually contains fixed length header with the total content length in it. For example you could always send 1 byte that indicates the total length of the content in bytes, which would support up to 255 bytes.

Comment: Or you can do like SMTP does, and include a terminator string (. on it's own line)

Answer (score 3):

As other answers indicated, TCP is a *stream* protocol -- every byte sent will be received (once and in the same order), but there are no intrinsic "message boundaries" -- whether all bytes are sent in a single `.send` call, or multiple ones, they might still be received in one or multiple `.receive` calls.

So, if you need "message boundaries", you need to impose them *on top* of the TCP stream, IOW, essentially, at application level.  For example, if you know the bytes you're sending will never contain a `\0`, null-terminated strings work fine; various methods of "escaping" let you send strings of bytes which obey no such limitations.  (There are existing protocols for this but none is really widespread or widely accepted).

Answer (score 2):

Basically as far as TCP goes it only guarantees that the data sent from one end to the other end will be sent in the same order.
Now usually what you'll have to do is have an internal buffer that keeps looping until it has received your 1000 byte "packet".
Because the recv command as mentioned returns how much has actually been received.
So usually you'll have to then implement a protocol on top of TCP to make sure you send data at an appropriate speed. Because if you send() all the data in one run through it will overload the under lying networking stack, and which will cause complications.
So usually in the protocol there is a tiny acknowledgement packet sent back to confirm that the packet of 1000 bytes are sent.

Answer (score 2):

You decide, in your message that how many bytes your message shall contain. For instance in your case its 1000. Following is up and running C# code to achieve the same. The method returns with 1000 bytes. The abort code is 0 bytes; you can tailor that according to your needs.

**Usage:**

```
strMsg = ReadData(thisTcpClient.Client, 1000, out bDisconnected);
```

**Following is the method:**

```
    string ReadData(Socket sckClient, int nBytesToRead, out bool bShouldDisconnect)
    {
        bShouldDisconnect = false;

        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[nBytesToRead];
        Array.Clear(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);

        int nDataRead = 0;
        int nStartIndex = 0;

        while (nDataRead < nBytesToRead)
        {

            int nBytesRead = sckClient.Receive(byteBuffer, nStartIndex, nBytesToRead - nStartIndex, SocketFlags.None);

            if (0 == nBytesRead)
            {
                bShouldDisconnect = true;
                //0 bytes received; assuming disconnect signal
                break;
            }

            nDataRead += nBytesRead;
            nStartIndex += nBytesRead;
        }

        return Encoding.Default.GetString(byteBuffer, 0, nDataRead);
    }
```

Let us know this didn't help you (0: Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a chance for receiving packets part by part. Hope this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxzt95kb(VS.80).aspx) and following example (taken from the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxzt95kb(VS.80).aspx) in msdn for quick review) would be helpful to you if you are using windows sockets.

```
void CChatSocket::OnReceive(int nErrorCode)
{
   CSocket::OnReceive(nErrorCode);

   DWORD dwReceived;

   if (IOCtl(FIONREAD, &dwReceived))
   {
      if (dwReceived >= dwExpected)   // Process only if you have enough data
         m_pDoc->ProcessPendingRead();
   }
   else
   {
      // Error handling here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP guarantees that they will recieve all 1000 bytes, but not necessarily in order (though, it will appear so to the recieving application) and not necessarily all at once (unless you craft the packet yourself and make it so.).

That said, for a packet as small as 1000 bytes, there is a good chance it'll send in one packet as long as you do it in one call to `send`, though for larger transmissions it may not.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley, from the TCP client's point of view, TCP does guarantee that it delivers the datagram in order. The underlying IP doesn't so it might re-order them, but that's internal details of TCP.

Comment: So are packets. But the OP is worried about them. You are right, and I aluded to that in saying that the recieving application will always recieve them in order. But they aren't necessarily delivered to the computer in order.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that the TCP layer guarantees is that the receiver will receive:

- all the bytes transmitted by the sender
- in the same order

There are no guarantees at all about how the bytes might be split up into "packets". All the stuff you might read about MTU, packet fragmentation, maximum segment size, or whatever else is all below the layer of TCP sockets, and is irrelevant. TCP provides a stream service *only*.

With reference to your question, this means that the receiver may receive the first 500 bytes, then the next 500 bytes later. Or, the receiver might receive the data one byte at a time, if that's what it asks for. This is the reason that the `recv()` function takes a parameter that tells it how much data to *return*, instead of it telling you *how big a packet is*.

Answer (score -1):

The transmission control protocol guarantees successful delivery of all packets by requiring acknowledgment of the successful delivery of each packet to the sender by the receiver.  By this definition the receiver will always receive the payload in chunks when the size of the payload exceeds the [MTU (maximum transmission unit)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTU_%28networking%29).

For more information please read [Transmission Control Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).

Comment: by "packet size" you mean for example the IPv4's limit to 65,507 bytes?

Comment: Sorry, I meant MTU - I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: TCP guarantees successful delivery of data, but not packets - see my response about retransmission.

Answer (score -1):

The IP packets may get fragmented during retransmission.

So the destination machine may receive multiple packets - which will be reassembled back by TCP/IP stack. Depending on the network API you are using - the data will be given to **you** either reassembled or in RAW packets.

Answer (score -1):

It depends of the stablished MTU (Maximum transfer unit). If your stablished connection (once handshaked) refers to a MTU of 512 bytes you will need two or more TCP packets to send 1000 bytes.