# recv() links messages

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I've got a piece of code:

```
while(1) {
    if(recvfrom(*val, buffer, 1024, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL)==-1) {    
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    } else printf("recv msgpeek\n");
    if(*(int*)buffer>5) {
        if(recvfrom(*val, buffer, 1024, 0, NULL, NULL)==-1) {   
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        } else printf("recv\n");
        if(*(int*)buffer==6) {
                    printf("%d\n", *(int*)(buffer+sizeof(int)+30));
                    printf("%s\n", (char*)buffer+sizeof(int));
                }
   }
```

This is part of a client programme. I'm sending messages from server to this client and I've noticed that when client receives this messages, they're connected. I'm using SOCK_STREAM type sockets. Anyone know how to avoid connecting messages?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid connecting messages, I want to get them as I send them - as two separate messages.

Comment: TCP, I'm using SOCK_STREAM while I create sockets

Comment: If this is TCP, why are you using `recvfrom`?  Try using `recv` instead.

Comment: @Adam Now, I'm using it, I was just trying to fix the problem in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are reading from TCP socket, and expecting to get exactly same number of bytes as you "sent" from the other side. Here you assumption is wrong. TCP socket is a *bi-directional stream*, i.e. it does not preserve boundaries of the application messages you send through it. A "write" on one side of the connection could result in multiple "reads" on the other side, and the other way around, multiple "writes" could be received together. That last case is what you are seeing. It is your responsibility to keep track of message boundaries.

Related question - [Receiving data in TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623197/receiving-data-in-tcp).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your problem is that you send 2 for example messages but you receive one, containing the contents of the two messages sent. This is due to the Nagle's algorithm that TCP uses to improve efficiency. If you want to disable this algorithm use the `TCP_NODELAY` option.

Comment: No, this is due to fundamental nature of TCP.

Comment: Yeah this fundamental nature uses the Nagles's algorithm. The man page of tcp says that if the TCP_NODELAY option is set, you disable this behaviour.

Comment: No, Nagle algorithm is an optimization. The fundamental nature of TCP is that it gives you a *stream* not "messages".

Comment: Ok, so the Nagle's is a system depended optimazation? Eg Linux supports it, maybe other systems not? (That would mean that you can not send distinct "messages" in these systems without this option?)

Comment: Nagle is an optimization of the base TCP to reduce number of small IP packets flowing on the wide internet, and thus improve the *throughput*. You only disable Nagle when you need low *latency*, say, in remote interactive programs like telnet. TCP does not now about application messages. You have to design your own *application protocol* on top on TCP stream to deal with those (fixed length messages, length prefixes, messages delimiters are some of your options).

Comment: Good to know it. Until now, if I had to send a certain message either I used UDP or the TCP_NODELAY option :P

Comment: There's more ... :) Get this book http://www.kohala.com/start/unp.html - you'd be amazed.

Comment: Thanks! I put it at my TODO list :D